# How do we ignore a folder of images with SVN tortoise without unversioning?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am a total noob at this, but in my understanding there were files inside the folder that were versioned and I can't ignore the entire folder without committing the unversioning of the versioned files. Is there a way around this?

I tried doing unversion and ignore this folder recursively, but it adds the files that were committed by someone else and highlights them in red when I try to commit. This is annoying, because I don't want the image files to be there in the first place.